# How to activate/deactivate a gnome-shell extension from command line

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

Let's say I have successully installed my set of gnome-shell extensions.
But I want to deactivate/unactivate from the command line. This is only possible via mouse action, AFAIK.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is well described in the [Gnome wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions#Enabling_extensions), quoting:

> You can do this with the GSettings key, org.gnome.shell.enabled-extensions, or several tools that manipulate this GSettings key, such as GNOME Tweak Tool or a recent version of gnome-shell-extension-tool.

If you invoke `gnome-shell-extension-tool --help`, you will see that it is capable of enabling and disabling extensions by their name. For example, the following command enables user themes:

```
gnome-shell-extension-tool -e user-theme
```

Oh, and you can get the names of all your locally installed extensions by doing `ls ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. It will give you entries of the form `the-name@author`.

Comment: It doesn't work if the extension has not been installed. It only changes the settings in dconf.

Comment: In newer versions (I'm on 19.10), `gnome-shell-extension-tool` has been superseded by the more powerful `gnome-extensions`.  This allows useful queries against the running env, eg: `gnome-extensions list` to get a list of installed extensions and `gnome-extensions info $extension`, where `$extension` can be obtained from the list

Comment: as you said "in newer versions" which means that not all distributions (I would dare to say still most distributions) don't have 'gnome-extensions' installed, some even don't have repos that contains 'gnome-extensions' by default

Comment: is there a gui for this?

Comment: @chovy GNOME Tweaks includes a section for managing extensions. Install `gnome-tweaks`, then launch the Tweaks application, then navigate to the "Extensions" tab.

Answer (score 21):

You can see a list of extensions installed with the following command

```bsh
gnome-extensions list
```

From the list you can enable/disable any extension like this:

```bsh
gnome-extensions enable user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
gnome-extensions disable user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

Notice the full extension name is needed.

Comment: This way of doing is as of today gnome idiomatic,  I do not know if I should update the answer

Comment: not all distribution has or make it easy to install 'gnome-extensions'