# Gnome on Ubuntu 18.04 is crashing after logging in

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, crash

After logging in into Ubuntu I'm able to see my desktop for about 1-2 seconds, and then I'm automatically logged out. Here is a part of `/var/log/syslog`, that probably contains the solution for this situation:

```
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski nautilus-deskto[4134]: Can not get _NET_WORKAREA
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski nautilus-deskto[4134]: Can not determine workarea, guessing at layout
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski dropbox.desktop[4149]: dropbox: load fq extension '/home/dlakomski/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-62.4.103/tornado.speedups.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski dropbox.desktop[4149]: dropbox: load fq extension '/home/dlakomski/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-62.4.103/cpuid.compiled._cpuid.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski gnome-shell[4183]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski dropbox.desktop[4149]: dropbox: load fq extension '/home/dlakomski/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-62.4.103/linuxffi.resolv.compiled._linuxffi_resolv.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski gnome-shell[4183]: type name 'Gjs_Unite.Settings' contains invalid characters
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski gnome-shell[4183]: g_type_set_qdata: assertion 'node != NULL' failed
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: **
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: Gjs:ERROR:gi/object.cpp:2024:void gjs_define_object_class(JSContext*, JS::HandleObject, GIObjectInfo*, GType, JS::MutableHandleObject, JS::MutableHandleObject): assertion failed: (gtype != G_TYPE_INVALID)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: == Stack trace for context 0x5604b24f44d0 ==
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #0 0x7ffd06e7e9c0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:531 (0x7f32102bd4d8 @ 363)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #1 0x7ffd06e7ea20 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f32102b5de0 @ 71)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #2 0x7ffd06e7ead0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:114 (0x7f32102b5f78 @ 178)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #3 0x7ffd06e7eba0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:65 (0x7f32102b5cd0 @ 152)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #4 0x5604b291fe60 i   /home/dlakomski/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/unite@hardpixel.eu/convenience.js:7 (0x7f31a77abbc0 @ 278)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #5 0x5604b291fdc8 i   /home/dlakomski/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/unite@hardpixel.eu/handlers.js:3 (0x7f31a77ab340 @ 82)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #6 0x5604b291fd30 i   /home/dlakomski/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/unite@hardpixel.eu/module.js:3 (0x7f31a7782e68 @ 82)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #7 0x5604b291fc98 i   /home/dlakomski/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/unite@hardpixel.eu/modules/activateWindow.js:4 (0x7f31a7782cd0 @ 103)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #8 0x5604b291fc00 i   /home/dlakomski/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/unite@hardpixel.eu/extension.js:4 (0x7f31a7782918 @ 165)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #9 0x5604b291fb28 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:231 (0x7f31f065a450 @ 214)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #10 0x5604b291fa90 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:168 (0x7f31f065a2b8 @ 182)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #11 0x5604b291fa10 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:318 (0x7f31f065a9a0 @ 13)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #12 0x7ffd06e85020 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7f32102d2230 @ 386)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #13 0x5604b291f930 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:191 (0x7f31f065e120 @ 459)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #14 0x7ffd06e85c90 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f32102b5de0 @ 71)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #15 0x5604b291f8a0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:197 (0x7f31f065e230 @ 28)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #16 0x7ffd06e86990 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/fileUtils.js:27 (0x7f31f065e340 @ 323)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #17 0x5604b291f810 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:196 (0x7f31f065e1a8 @ 72)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #18 0x7ffd06e875f0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f32102b5de0 @ 71)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #19 0x5604b291f780 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:320 (0x7f31f065a918 @ 201)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #20 0x5604b291f700 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:328 (0x7f31f065aa28 @ 36)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #21 0x5604b291f680 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:359 (0x7f31f065ac48 @ 67)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #22 0x5604b291f5f8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:367 (0x7f31f065acd0 @ 41)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #23 0x5604b291f568 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:229 (0x7f32102da340 @ 1152)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #24 0x5604b291f4e0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:133 (0x7f32102da230 @ 237)
Dec  4 09:15:21 dlakomski org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4183]: #25 0x5604b291f468 i   <main>:1 (0x7f3210286b38 @ 48)
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski gnome-session[3737]: gnome-session-binary[3737]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 6
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski gnome-session-binary[3737]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 6
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski gnome-session[3737]: gnome-session-binary[3737]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski gnome-session-binary[3737]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski gnome-session-binary[3737]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski gnome-session[3737]: gnome-session-binary[3737]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski gnome-session-binary[3737]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski bluetoothd[1223]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski bluetoothd[1223]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski nautilus-deskto[4134]: nautilus-desktop: Fatal IO error 0 (Sukces) on X server :0.
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski gsd-power[4039]: gsd-power: Fatal IO error 11 (Zasoby chwilowo niedostępne) on X server :0.
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski kernel: [   25.769747] rfkill: input handler enabled
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski at-spi-bus-launcher[3853]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski at-spi-bus-launcher[3853]:       after 23 requests (23 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski gsd-xsettings[4056]: gsd-xsettings: Fatal IO error 11 (Zasoby chwilowo niedostępne) on X server :0.
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski gsd-wacom[4062]: gsd-wacom: Fatal IO error 11 (Zasoby chwilowo niedostępne) on X server :0.
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski gsd-clipboard[4072]: gsd-clipboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Zasoby chwilowo niedostępne) on X server :0.
Dec  4 09:15:22 dlakomski gsd-color[4078]: gsd-color: Fatal IO error 11 (Zasoby chwilowo niedostępne) on X server :0.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. It was problem with GNOME extension called `Unite`. After disabling it problem still occurred, so I had to completely remove it.

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/unite@hardpixel.eu
```

did the job :)

Comment: Thanks, had the same problem after upgrading kernel to 4.15.0-42.

Comment: The extension author has fixed this issue. It's still pending approval on extensions.gnome.org, but you can download it from Github before then: https://github.com/hardpixel/unite-shell/issues/76

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, you can remove all files of the offending extension.

You could also go a less invasive way (particular in case you are not sure if an extension is the problem)

1. list all extension names via `ls ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` to find the full name (including the url-part after the `@`)
2. disable the extension via `gnome-shell-extension-tool -d extensionname@url.abc` e.g. `gnome-shell-extension-tool -d unite@hardpixel.eu`
3. You enable the extension again using `-e` (like **e**nable) instead of `-d` (as **d**isable)

…which I know from ["How to activate/deactivate a gnome-shell extension from command line"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591757/how-to-activate-deactivate-a-gnome-shell-extension-from-command-line)

In case you want to check if any extension causes your problem, you could also enable/disable them all and then do the above for a more detailed diagnosis:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell disable-user-extensions true` (and, to restore the previous state, use `false` instead of `true`) ([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029376/how-to-enable-and-disable-gnome-extensions-from-command-line))

Comment: Disabling extension didn't work. I had to removed it completely to be able to log in.