# How do I automatically reinstall GNOME shell extensions after reinstalling Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

After reinstalling Ubuntu, my installed GNOME shell extensions are gone and I need to manually go to https://extensions.gnome.org/ to reinstall each one. Can this process be automated? For example, if I provide a file with the names of the extensions I want to install. Could I just run some command to reinstall them?

(Another idea: it would be even simpler if the extensions could be saved automatically at a GNOME account, similarly to the way extensions in Google Chrome are saved in my google account.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some extensions come with the standard Ubuntu software repository, and accordingly can be installed from Software Center or using the terminal with `sudo apt get`. These commands could be included in a script for automated installation.

Installation of extensions downloaded from the Gnome-Shell website can also be scripted. [This website](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions-from-zip-file-using-command-line-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) describes a possible process. Briefly,

1. The extension must be downloaded
2. The extensions UUID needs to be determined from the metadata.json file that comes with each extension.
3. The program files need to be copied under `.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`, in a folder that is named according to the UUID.

[To enable extensions with a command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591757/how-to-activate-deactivate-a-gnome-shell-extension-from-command-line), you can use `gnome-shell-extension-tool`.

Comment: I've [scripted the process](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/243133/213097) described in the tutorial (also valid to [20.04](https://linuxconfig.org/install-gnome-shell-extensions-from-zip-file-using-command-line-on-ubuntu-20-04-linux)). Hope it could be useful

Answer (score 3):

You're probably using the browser extensions (available for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/) and [Chromium/Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep?hl=en)) that helps to install GNOME shell extensions from [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/).

These extensions also let you sync your list of extensions. Open preferences of the extension and enable the '**Synchronise GNOME shell extensions list**' option:

[image]
and click '*Save*'.