# How to set workspaces in Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: panel, 21.10, top

How can a row of six workspaces be set in the top panel in Ubuntu 21.10?

Comment: Does [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1485/workspace-matrix/) extension work for you? It is much simpler to customize the desktop in MATE/KDE/XFCE. You may consider switching to one of them, if you plan to heavily customize the desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Gnome Tweaks, you can set a fixed number of workspaces using Gnome Tweaks, Workspaces tab . This option will be included in the main Gnome settings in future versions.

You then can set up a workspace indicator in the top bar using extensions.

Workspace Indicator by fmuellner is an official extension, which is part of the extensions for Gnome Classic (Gnome Shell configured like the classical Gnome 2, with application menu and task bar on the bottom). Install these extensions with the command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

Turn the extension "Workspace Indicator" on using the Extensions tool or using the [command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591757/how-to-activate-deactivate-a-gnome-shell-extension-from-command-line).

Gnome Tweaks and the Extensions tool are not installed by default. Install them using Software or with the command line:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```